# In Angular，how to handle the param when the param is a url?

Tags: angular

I want to post a url as the param in the route use Angular，like this：

http://localhost:1338/#/channel/token&http%3A%2F%2Fww.google.com

the key route is  `url: "/channel/:params"`,

but the page alaways go the default route.

when I post a param not a url, it works well,like this :
http://localhost:1338/#/channel/token&123

I don't know how to handle the param contains a url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use `:params` it means the string after `/` will be assigned in `params` there is no need of `token&` you can access URL directly by subscribing `params` from `Router` as:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(paramsData => {
    console.log(params['params']);
});
```

URL should be:

```
http://localhost:1338/#/channel/http%3A%2F%2Fww.google.com
```

> If you want to send more than one parameter use query string parameters. Also you can use any other character to separate params rather than `&` otherwise you have to subscribe both `params` & `queryParams` of `Router`

Comment: I think OP want to send two params token and URL

Comment: @PardeepJain yes updated the answer for that as well :)

Comment: Cool !!, You can send more than one params as normal parameter as well

Answer (score 0):

you can encode :

**var encoded = encodeURI(uri);**

and get the decoded value :

**decodeURI(encoded)**

Comment: That can be the alternate

Answer (score 0):

import ActivatedRoute

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

In Constructor write following code

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

write below code to get your params either in **ngOnInit()** or any other place

```
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['params'];
```